# Мятно(-)медовое пиво. Дефис нужен?

Tags: орфография

"Мятно(-)медовое пиво" — дефис нужен?

Answer (score 3):

Мятно-медовое пиво. Сложное прилагательное **с сочинительной связью основ двух прилагательных: мятный и медовый**, дефисное написание.

Comment: а то в инете даже сочетания такого нет..)

Comment: В этой теме очень много авторских слов, поэтому они не все отражаются в текстах и словарях.